# How to catch exceptions after Server.Transfer (whitout using customErrors)?

Tags: c#, asp.net, redirect, try-catch, server.transfer

I will simplify the example, so let's say we have `Page A`, `Page B` and `Page C`

1. `Page A` goes with `base.OnInit()` on `page B`,
2. `Page B` throws an exception and will be redirected with `Server.Transfer` to `Page C`.
3. `Page C` has a try / catch, where the exception should be catched.

I've been trying with `Server.GetLastError()`, has brought nothing (GetLastErros is null). How can you solve it and deal **without** adding `<customErrors>` in `web.config`?

The interesting thing is that when I'm debugging in `Page C`, I can see the variable `$exception`, which is set correctly.

Image -> http://www.picfront.org/d/8EeT

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Your *Page C* doesn't know anything about exceptions in *Page B*. The exception that is thrown in *Page B* is handled there.

I guess the `$exception` you're seeing in *Page C* is a non-public member of this pages stack trace.

To have your *Page C* act as a generic error handler, you'd have to hand over the information about the exception. You could do this in a querystring param, but I doubt this will be an easy maintainable solution.

Maybe using a Master Page, providing a generic event handler could offer a better solution instead of a dedicated page but I haven't tried this.

Comment: I think QueryString would not be the best choise, maybe some more ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Did you use below event in your `Web Page/Content Page/BasePage`.

```
protected override void OnError(EventArgs e)
{
     base.OnError(e);
}
```

Did you use `Application_Error` in `Global.asax` file?

```
void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      // Code that runs when an unhandled error occurs
}
```